# Docker overlay2 directory growing with each build (zero downtime docker compose deployment)

Tags: django, linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

**Problem:**

The host machine's /var/lib/docker/overlay2 directory keeps growing with each build until I'm forced to stop the containers and run `docker system prune -af` to free up space. Here's the ncdu of the overlay2 directory after just 2 or 3 deployments/builds (there are many additional directories, but they're cut off):

[image]

My deployment script for zero downtime keeps a set of containers always running.

Here's the script:

```
# sources:
# https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-update-docker-container-with-zero-downtime/

old_container=$(docker container ls --filter name=shipaware-django-* --filter status=running --latest | grep -o shipaware-django-[0-9].*)
old_listener=$(docker container ls --filter name=shipaware-listener-* --filter status=running --latest | grep -o shipaware-listener-[0-9].*)
# need to restart celery in case of new tasks
old_celeryworker=$(docker container ls --filter name=shipaware-celeryworker-* --filter status=running --latest | grep -o shipaware-celeryworker-[0-9].*)
old_celerybeat=$(docker container ls --filter name=shipaware-celerybeat-* --filter status=running --latest | grep -o shipaware-celerybeat-[0-9].*)
echo "old_container: $old_container"

docker compose -f production.yml up -d --scale django=2 --scale listener=2 --scale celeryworker=2 --scale celerybeat=2 --no-recreate --build
echo "scaled  up django and listener to 2 containers"

echo "sleeping 60s"
sleep 60

docker container stop $old_container
docker container stop $old_listener
docker container stop $old_celeryworker
docker container stop $old_celerybeat
echo "stopped $old_container"

docker container rm $old_container
docker container rm $old_listener
docker container rm $old_celeryworker
docker container rm $old_celerybeat
echo "removed $old_container"

docker compose -f production.yml up -d --scale django=1 --scale listener=1 --scale celeryworker=1 --scale celerybeat=1 --no-recreate
echo "scaled back down to 1 container"
```

Here's the production.yml docker compose file for the application server (the database runs on a separate server):

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  production_traefik: { }

x-django: &django
    depends_on:
      - redis
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
      target: django
    volumes:
      # needed for nginx to access the project's static files
      - ./staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
    restart: unless-stopped

services:
  django:
    <<: *django
    image: shipaware_django_production_django
    command:
      - /start

  listener:
    <<: *django
    depends_on:
      - django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
      target: listener
    image: shipaware_django_production_listener

  nginx: # https://stackoverflow.com/a/51903852/2469390
    image: nginx:1.25-alpine
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./staticfiles:/static

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    expose:
      - 44444
    restart: unless-stopped

  redis:
    image: redis:6
    restart: unless-stopped

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: shipaware_django_production_celeryworker
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: shipaware_django_production_celerybeat
    command: /start-celerybeat

  traefik:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/traefik/Dockerfile
    image: shipaware_django_production_traefik
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - production_traefik:/etc/traefik/acme:z
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

**The temporary solution**

Run another script in the early AM over the weekend to stop all containers, run `docker system prune -af`, then restart the containers. This results in several minutes of downtime.

**My question:**

I'm hitting a wall with either my understanding of docker or its ability for zero downtime deployments on a single application server without eventually running out of disk space on the host machine.

With just one dockerized application server, is it possible to prevent the disk space creep of overlay2 without downtime? Or do I need to run a second server.

If additional server(s) are the answer, what's the best approach given my current setup (blue green deployment, load balancer, etc.)?